# Extract a tab from a worksheet and save as a new file in a specific directory, with the file name being today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to copy the data from one tab in Excel, paste the data into a new worksheet, and save the new worksheet into a specific directory with today's date being the name of the newly saved file.

How can I do this using VBA?

It's going to happen every day at the same exact time. I figured I would use a combination of onTime and whatever script people help me with here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though your post is a request for SO contributors to write your code for you. Unfortunately, that's not what this website is for. Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' and specifically these guidelines. Be sure to read some of the links in the quidelines as well >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

This only needs a couple lines of code in VBA:

```
Sub SaveSheet1()
    'This will copy the sheet and by default stick it in a new workbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    'That new workbook is now the "ActiveWorkbook" so save it.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\my_new_workbook" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xls")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the tab name which can be changed very easily by a user, I'd suggest using the sheet's codename instead.